# send ZPL raw data from linux to Windows shared printer in Java

Tags: java, linux, zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I've Zebra ZM400 (300dpi) Label Printer which is connected on Windows PC via USB and I've shared that printer to everyone with `\\WindowsIPAddress\\zd`.

My Java is on `Linux Redhat` server and I've added that printer using `Windows Printer via SAMBA` method.

When I test printed, no label came out so I traced my program but I can't find any error yet label cannot printed.

This is my code.

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("\\\\WindowsIPAddress\zd");

            String commands = "CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~" +
                    "^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR2,2~SD15^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ" +
                    "~DG000.GRF,60928,112," +
                    ",::::::::::::::::::::::::N07FpOF8,M0pSFC0,L03FpSF8,L0pUFE,K01FpUF,K07FpUFC0K0IFC0pO03FFE0K0HF80pQ03FE0J01FE0pS0HF0J03FC0pS07F8J03F80pS03F8J07F0pT01FCJ07E0pU0FCJ0FE0pU0FEJ0FC0pU07E:::I01FC0pU07EI01F80pU07E::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::J0F80pU07EJ0FC0pU07E:::J07E0pU0FC:J07F0pT01FCJ03F80pS03F8J03FC0pS07F8J01FE0pS0HF0K0HF80pQ03FE0K0pWFE0K07FpUFC0K01FpUF,L0pUFE,L03FpSF8,M0pSFC0,,::::::::::::::~DG001.GRF,16128,056," +
                    ",:::::::::::gY0AFJFEA0,gX01FLFD0,gW0ABFMFA80,gU057FQFC,gV0IFEFHFEFHFEFA,gS015FUF0,gT02FTFE0,gS05FWF40,gS0YFE0,gR01FXFD0,gR0gGFA,gQ07FgGFC0,gQ0EFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFE80,gO015FgIF1,gP03FgIF8,gO07FgKF,gO07FgKF80,g01010J017FgKFD0,gG0HA80I03FgLFE0,g057540I07FgMF4,Y0EFHFHEI0IFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFE,W017FLF47FgOFC0,X0BFKFA03FgNFE80,W07FMFD7FgOFC0,V02FhFE8,V01FhGF8,V03FhGF8,V07FhGFC,U02FEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFE,T017FhIFC0,U03FhIF80,T017FhIFD0,T03FhKF8,:T0BFhKFA,T07FhKFE,T0FEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFE,S01FhMFC0,S01FhMF80,S03FhMFC0,S03FhMFE0,S07FhNF0,S0hPF8,S0hPF4,S0EFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFC,R01FhPF,S0hPFE,R05FhPFC0,R03FhPF80,R07FhPFC0,::R07FFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFHE0,Q017FhQF80T0K1,R0hSF8,R07FhQFC0T057FHF40,R0hSFC0T0KFE8,Q01FhRFD0S05FKF4,R0hSFE0S0NF80,Q01FhSFS05FMF40,Q02FEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFE0R06FEFEFEFEE0,O015FhTF80010L017FOFD,P02FhTF80P03FOF8,O017FhTFC0P07FPF,P0hVF80P0QFE,N017FhYFD510I07FQFD0,N01FiHFE80H07FQFE0,N01FiIF40H07FRF0,N03FFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFE801FFEFHFEFHFEFHF8,M01FiLFD7FSFD,N0iMF83FSFA,M07FjIF,M03FjHFE,L01FjJF,L01FjJF80,L05FjJF80,L07EFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEA0,K01FjLF0,L0jLFE0,K05FjLF0,K01FjKFE0,K07FjLF4,K0jNF8,K07FjLF4,K0HFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEAHAEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFAAEFHFEFC,J07FgSFD0105FhFD575FIFD,J03FgSF80H03FhFH8B3FIFE,J07FgSF40H05FhHFH7JFE,J03FgSFJ03FhFAE23FIFE,I017FgSF40H05FhHF53FJF,I01FgTF80H03FhFAF03FIFE,I01FgTF40H05FhHF43FIFE,I02FEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEF80H02FEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFAEABEFEFE,I07FgTFD5005FhOF,I03FgTFC8003FhNFE,I07FgVFH05FhOF,I03FgUFE003FhNFE,H017FgVFH05FhOF,I0gXFH03FhOF,H017FgVFH05FhOF,H01EFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFHEH02FHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFE,H01FgWFH05FhOF,H01FgWFH03FhOF,H01FgWFH05FhOF,H03FgVFE003FhNFE,H03FUF57FNFD5FNFH05FPFD55FSFH5gF,H03FNF80H03E0H03FLFC00BFMFH03FOF80I0QFA80J083FSFE,H07FNFC0H07D0H07FLFC00FNFH05FOF40H017FOFD4005I57FTF,H03EFEFEFEFE80H0380I0FEFEFEF8003EFEFEFEE002FEFEFEFEFC0J02FEFEFEFEFE80L03EFEFEFEFEFEFEFE,017FNF80H07D0H01FLFD007FMFH05FNFD0I017FOFC0L07FTF,H0BFNF80H030J03FKF8003FMFH03FMFE80K0OFE0M03FSFE,H0PF80N07FKFI01FMFH05FMFC0L07FMF40M07FSFE,H0PF80N02FKFI03FLFE003FMFE0L03FMFO03FSFE,01FOF80J010H01FKFI01FMFH05FMFC0L03FMFI0H5H0157FSFE,H0PFA80N0LF8003FMFH03FMF80M0MFE0H0BE800AFTFE,01FOFD40I050I0LFI01FMFH05FMF80H040I0NFH017F40177FSFE,H0FEFHFEFHFEFE0H02FE0H06FHFEF8003FFEFHFHEH02FHFEFHFE0H02FE0H0HFEFHFEA002FFA007FEFHFEFHFEFHFEFC,01FQFI07FF0H07FJF8003FMFH05FMFI07FD0H0NF017FHF017FTFD,01FPFE0H0IFI03FJF800BFMFH03FLFE0H0HFE8007FKFA00FHFE003FTF8,01FQFH01FHFC007FKF05FNFH05FLFC003FHFC007FKFC017FHF407FTF4,01FPFE0H0IFC003FJFE00FMFE003FLFC002FHF8007FKFA00FIFH03FTF0,01FQFH01FHFC007FVFH05FLFC007FHFC005FKFC01FIF407FTF0,01FPFE003FHFE003FVFH03FLFC003FHFC001FKF800FIF803FSFE0,01FPFE007FHFE007FVFH05FLFC007FHFC005FKFC017FHF407FTF0,H0FEFEFEFEFEFE002EFEE002FEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEE002FEFEFEF8007EFEC0H0FEFEFEA00EFEE002FEFEFEFEFEFEFEE0,01FQFH07FHFE007FVFH05FLFC007FHFC005FKFC017FHF407FTF0,01FPFE003FHFE003FVFH03FLF8007FHFE001FKFA003FFE003FSF80,01FQFH07FHFE007FVFH05FLF4007FHFC005FKFE007FFC007FSF,01FPFE002FHFE003FUFE003FLFI07FHFE001FKFA002FFA003FSF,01FQFH07FIFH07FVFH05FLF4007FHFD005FLFH015D0017FSF,01FPFE003FHFE003FVFH03FLF8007FHFE001FKFE0M0TFE,01FPFE007FHFE007FVFH05FLF4007FHFC005FLF40K017FRFE,01FEFHFEFHFEFE003FFEE002FHFEFHFEFHFEFHFHEH02FHFEFHF8007EFFC001FEFHFEF80K03FFEFHFEFHFEFHF8,01FQF017FHFC007FVFH05FLF4007FHFC005FLF40K01FSF9,01FPFE003FHFC007FVFH03FLF8007FHFC001FLFE0K03FSF0,01FQFH07FHF4007FVFH05FLFC007FHFC005FMFC0I057FRFC0,01FPFE002FHF8007FUFE003FLFC003FHF8003FMF80I02FSF80,01FQFH07FHFI0LFD57FNFH05FLFC003FHFC007FMFC05H5UF80,H0QFE003FFE0H0LF800FNFH03FLFC0H0HFE800FMFE80BAFTFC,01FPFE007FFE0H0LFC01FNFH05FLFC001FHFI07FMFH07FUFC,H0FEFEFEFEFEFE002EF8002EFEFEF800FEFEFEFEE0H0FEFEFEFE0H02FE0H0EFEFEFEF802FEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEE8,01FQFH07FF9001FKF801FNFH05FMFI07FD0H0NFD01FVF0,H0BFOFE0I080H03FKFI03FKFE80H0BFKFE80H080I0NF800FUF80,H07FPFN07FKFI03FKFE0I01FLFC0L07FMF400557FRF,H0BFOFE0M07FJFE0H03FKFE0I01FLF80L03FLFE0H0H2AFQFE,H07FPFM01FLFI01FKFE0I01FLFC0L07FMFK0I5QF,H0BFOFE0M0MFI03FKFE0I01FLF80L07FLFE0L0BFOFE,H07FOFE0L07FLFI01FKFE0I01FLFE0L0OF40K017FOF,H03EFHFEFHFEFE0L07FEFHFEF8001FFEFHFE0I01FFEFHFEF80J02FHFEFHFEF80L02FEFHFEFHFE,H03FPFL017FLFD001FLFJ01FMFD0J07FNFD0L01FOF,H03FOFE0K0BFMFC001FKFE0I03FNF80H03FOFE80L0OFE,H01FPFH01557FNFD001FgGFI5RFN07FNF,H01FOFE002003FNFE003FLFHAEABFNFE002FPFE0M07FMFE,H01FPFH03FRFH01FgUF401510I07FNF,H01FOFE003FRFH03FgUF80280J03FMFE,H017FNFE003FRFH03FgUF417FF74007FNF,I06FEFEFEFEFE003EFEFEFEFEFEFE003EFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFE800EFEFA003EFEFEFEFE,H017FOFH03FRFH07FgTFC01FIFD017FNFQ0I1,I03FNFE003FQFC00BFgTF803FIFE003FMFE0Q0BFE8,I07FOFH07FQFC00FgUFH01FIFE007FNFQ07FIF40,I03FNFE003FQF800FgUF803FIFE007FMFE0P03FHFE,I01FOFH03FQF801FgUFH01FIFD017FNFP01FKF0,I01FNFE003FQF800FgUF800FIFA00FNFE0P0KFE0,I01FNFE001FQFH05FgUFH017FHF400FOFP07FKF4,J07FFEFHFHEJ03FEFHFEFHFEC006FHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFE80022A0H02FEFHFEFHFE0O0FEFHFEFE,I017FMF10H03FOFD007FgUF80015D5001FOFO01FMF,J03FLFE0I03FOFE00FgVFA0M03FNFE0N01FLFE,J07FLFE0I03FPF87FgWFM017FNFE0N07FMF40,J03FLFE0I03FPF83FgVFE0M07FNFE0N07FMF80,J01FMFJ03FPFDFgXF40K05FOFE0M01FNFC0,K0MFE0I03FPF8FgXF80K03FOFE0N0OFC0,K07FLFJ07FhQF40I057FOFC0M01FNFE0,K02FEFEFEFAJAFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEEA002AFEFEFEFEFEFC0M03EFEFEFEFEE0,K07FLFDFDFhTFJ5RFD0M07FOF0,K01FjFC0M03FNFE8,L0jGFC0M07FOFC,L0jGFC0M03FOF8,L07FiYFC0L017FOFC,L07FiYF80M07FOF8,L05FiYF40L017FOFC,M0EFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFFE0N07FFEFHFEFHFC,L01FiYFN017FOFC,M03FiWFE0N0QFC,M01FiXFN017FOFC,N0iXFE0N0QFC,N07FiWFN017FOFC,N0BFiVFA0N0QFC,N01FiVFC0M017FOFC,O02FEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFE80N07EFEFEFEFEFC,N017FiUF80M017FOFC,P0iVF80N03FOF8,O017FiTFP07FOFC,P02FiTFP03FNFE8,P017FiSFP07FOF8,Q02FiRFE0O03FNFE8,R07FiQFE0O03FNFE0,S02FEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEF80P0HFEFHFEFFE0,Q0H15FiPFD0O01FNFC0,U0ABBAA0FiIF80P0OFC0,T0H57FF55FiIF80P07FMFC0,gG03FiHFR03FMF,gG07FiGFD0Q01FMF,gG03FiGFE0Q01FLFE,gG01FiGFC0R07FKFC,gH07EFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFE80R03EFEFEE0,gG017FiFC0R05FKF4,gH03FiF80S0BFIFA0,gH07FiFT01FJFC0,gH02FhYFE0U0BFF8,gH01FhYFD0U01550,gI0iF80V0A80,gI07FhXFC,gI02FHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFFE0,gI03FhXF0,gJ0hXFC0,:gJ03FhVF,gJ01FhVF,gK0hVFE,gK07FhTFC,gL0FEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEE0,gK05FhTF0,gL0BFhRFA0,gK01FhSFC0,gL03FhRF,gL017FhQF,gM0hRFA,gM07FgOF7FYF0,gN07FFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFC0EFHFEFHFEFHFEFHFEFF80,gM017FgMFD1FXFD0,gN02FgLFE003FVFE,gN07FgMFH07FWF,gO03FgKF80H03FTFE8,gO01FgKFJ01FTFD0,gO02FgJFA0J0UF80,gP05FgIFL05FRFC,gP03EFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEE0L0BEFEFEFEFEFEF8,gP017FgGFD0K0H1QFD0,gR0gGF80O0BFMF8,gQ01FgFD0N017FMF4,gS0YFE0R0AFHFE8,gR0H1WFD0S0I1010,gT0WFA,gT05FTFD0,gU0EFHFEFHFEFHFEFFE0,gU017FQFD,gX0BFLFEA80,gW057FMFD40,gY02AFHFEA80,,::::::::::::::::::::::::::^XA" +
                    "^MMT" +
                    "^PW976" +
                    "^LL1126" +
                    "^LS0" +
                    "^FT482,122^A0N,58,57^FH\\^FD" + orderCode + "^FS" +
                    "^FT137,312^A0N,58,57^FH\\^FD" + voShippingInfo.get("CUSTOMER_NAME") + "^FS" +
                    "^FT137,399^A0N,42,40^FH\\^FD" + Address + "^FS" +
                    "^FT329,477^A0N,42,40^FH\\^FD" + postal_code + "^FS" +
                    "^FT32,544^XG000.GRF,1,1^FS" +
                    "^FT64,1088^XG001.GRF,1,1^FS" +
                    "^FT137,125^A0N,63,62^FH\\^FDOrder Code^FS" +
                    "^FT137,222^A0N,58,62^FH\\^FDDeliver to:^FS" +
                    "^FT61,747^A0N,42,40^FH\\^FDProudly brought to you by^FS" +
                    "^FT137,476^A0N,42,40^FH\\^FDCountry^FS" +
                    "^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ" +
                    "^XA^ID000.GRF^FS^XZ" +
                    "^XA^ID001.GRF^FS^XZ";

            os.write(commands.getBytes());
            os.close();
```

I tried from my localhost which is on Windows is ok but when I tested from Linux Server, nothing come out.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A couple of troubleshooting ideas - Does the data light on the front of the printer flash when you send the print job?  Also, can you send the string without encoding to bytes?  The printer wants the string just like it is in your code, not encoded as bytes.

Comment: One more thing regarding when you got the blank label - I usually consider a blank label a good thing in that I know communication is working, but that there is something wrong with my ZPL code.  If you can revert to the code that you had when you got the blank label, try some very simple ZPL like: 
^XA
^FT7,87
^A0N,87,122^FDTEST^FS
^XZ

Comment: @pitprog, i already tried to send string.. like ur ZPL.. but it's not working.. printer light is not blinking when i sent data